# Make and filter a dictionary in Python 3

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm currently kind of a noob in Python. I want to turn 2 lists I have into one dictionary. The lists are of equal size. I am able to make the dictionary like this:

e.g.

```
    names = ["start",\
     "dorpstraat",\
     "algemeen fonds",\
     "brink",\
     "inkomstenbelasting",\
     "station zuid",\
     "steenstraat",\
     "kans",\
     "ketelstraat",\
     "velperplein",\
     "gevangenis",\
     "barteljorisstraat",\
     "elecriciteitsbedrijf",\
     "zijlweg",\
     "houtstraat",\
     "station west",\
     "neude",\
     "algemeen fonds",\
     "biltstraat",\
     "vreeburg",\
     "vrij parkeren",\
     "a-kerkhof",\
     "kans",\
     "groote markt",\
     "heerestraat",\
     "station noord",\
     "spui",\
     "plein",\
     "waterleiding",\
     "lange poten",\
     "naar de gevangenis",\
     "hofplein",\
     "blaak",\
     "algemeen fonds",\
     "coolsingel",\
     "station oost",\
     "kans",\
     "leidschestraat",\
     "extra belasting",\
     "klaverstraat"]

    values = [0, 60, 0, 60, 0, 200, 100, 0, 100, 120,\
      0, 140, 120, 140, 160, 200, 180, 0, 180, 200,\
      0, 220, 0, 220, 240, 200, 260, 260, 150, 280,\
      0, 300, 300, 0, 320, 200, 0, 380, 0, 400]
```

This is how I turn them into a dictionary:

```
    dictionary = dict(zip(names, values))
```

When I print that dictionary I get this:

```
   {'start': 0, 'dorpstraat': 60, 'algemeen fonds': 0, 'brink': 60, 'inkomstenbelasting': 0, 'station zuid': 200, 'steenstraat': 100, 'kans': 0, 'ketelstraat': 100, 'velperplein': 120, 'gevangenis': 0, 'barteljorisstraat': 140, 'elecriciteitsbedrijf': 120, 'zijlweg': 140, 'houtstraat': 160, 'station west': 200, 'neude': 180, 'biltstraat': 180, 'vreeburg': 200, 'vrij parkeren': 0, 'a-kerkhof': 220, 'groote markt': 220, 'heerestraat': 240, 'station noord': 200, 'spui': 260, 'plein': 260, 'waterleiding': 150, 'lange poten': 280, 'naar de gevangenis': 0, 'hofplein': 300, 'blaak': 300, 'coolsingel': 320, 'station oost': 200, 'leidschestraat': 380, 'extra belasting': 0, 'klaverstraat': 400}
```

When I execute this:

```
    non_zero_ dictionary = {k: v for k, v in dictionary.items() if v != 0}
```

I get the dictionary like I want to. After that I want to make the dictionary so that the key becomes an element from names (the list) and I want to set all the values to False.

Comment: What, **exactly** is the output you want? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Shorten you example snippets, :/

Comment: also, you don't need `\\` at ends of lines in between braces, brackets, parens

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)).  By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would that do what you want?

```
no_false_dictionary = {
  key: False
  for key, value in zip(names, values)
  if value != 0
}
```

The second parameter in `key: False` is the value you want to set. In your case you seem not to care about the values so you end up with setting False everywhere.

Since you don't care about the values why no just do this instead?

```
your_non_zero = [
  name
  for name, value in zip(names, values)
  if value != 0
]
```

It's technically the same thing but doesn't make a dict out of it.

Comment: @sybren if that solves your problem, you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
no_false_dictionary = {key: False for key in non_zero_ dictionary}
```

Answer (score 1):

since your question isn't clear, i'll hazard a guess:

```
{name: False for name, val in zip(names, vals) if val}
```